# Count Distinct Not Working in Case Select Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL question in which the code fails to count distinct ID's.  It does count them, but does not do so distinctly. I have provided a small snippet of code below and have bolded the issue.

```
 SELECT
"RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESORT" AS "RESORT",
"RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE" AS "BUSINESS_DATE",
 to_char("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE",'MON-yyyy') AS "MONTHYEAR",
 Extract(day from "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE") AS "DAY",  
 Extract(month from "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE") AS "MONTH",
 Extract(year from "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE") AS "YEAR",
 "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" AS "SOURCE_CODE",
 "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."MARKET_CODE" AS "MARKET_CODE",
 "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" AS "RATE_CODE",
 "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID" AS "RESV_NAME_ID",
     (CASE WHEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" = 'GDS' 
          AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" NOT IN ('BKIT', 'EXPEDIA')
          AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."MARKET_CODE" NOT IN ('GOVG', 'ENT')
     THEN 'GDS'
     ELSE 'Other'
END) AS "BizUnit",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" = 'GDS' 
          AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" NOT IN ('BKIT', 'EXPEDIA')
          AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."MARKET_CODE" NOT IN ('GOVG', 'ENT')
     THEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID" 
ELSE NULL   
END) AS "COST",

(SUM("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE" - "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE_CREATED")/(COUNT      ("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE_CREATED"))) AS "DIFF",
SUM(NVL("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."NIGHTS",0)) AS "NIGHTS",
SUM(NVL("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."ROOM_REVENUE",0)) AS "ROOM_REVENUE"
FROM "OPERA"."RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY" "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"
Where RESORT in     ('558339','558341','4856','558340','602836','HCA','HZSD', 'TAC') and
BUSINESS_DATE < SYSDATE AND EXTRACT(year FROM "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE_CREATED") >=2016
GROUP BY
"RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESORT",
"RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE",
  to_char("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE",'MON-yyyy'),
  Extract(day from "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE"),  
 Extract(month from "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE"),
 Extract(year from "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."BUSINESS_DATE"),
  "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE",
  "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."MARKET_CODE",
  "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE", 
  "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID",

  (  CASE 
WHEN (("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" = 'GDS') AND ("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" != 'BKIT' OR "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" != 'EXPEDIA'
)) THEN 'GDS'
ELSE 'Other'
END )
```

Comment: You must be kidding!!! Minimize the query, use formatted text.

Comment: Your SQL is really crazy. I don't know where to start... SQL is not a programming language. It's a query language. From my first view I would say you should think of your general approach and change it. Think more simple.

Comment: "I have provided a small snippet of code" By the standards of this site, that is not a small snippet of code.

Comment: @ora-600 This is very basic SQL. @BuffaloBill: For readability, you should learn to utilize the `in` statement. You can easily get this down to `RATE_CODE not in ('BKIT', 'EXPEDIA', 'SPEXP', '...')`

Comment: the case doesn't make sense.  Case evaluates line by line to return a value which can then be aggregated.  Aggregation within the case doesn't make sense to me; around the case yes, within the case no.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code. I have updated it, so it is easier to read. Robbie, I know all about NOT IN, IN. I did not write this code.  It gets very complex with all of the codes included. It does COUNT correctly, just not distinctly.

Comment: xQbert - so place the count distinct around the case select?

Comment: Ora, crazy? This is basic stuff here.

Comment: @BuffaloBill (to ping somebody, you need to put `@` in front of their name): As xQbert mentioned, your count should go outside of your case statement. Your case statement should return a value as it evaluates each row, and then you can count(), sum(), etc, that value. You could do something like `count (distinct case when ([...]) then RESV_NAME_ID else RESV_NAME_ID end) AS COST`. (note that your query seems to return resv_name_id for cost, no matter what)

Comment: In an earlier edit, `"RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID"` was included in the group by clause so the count distinct would be at most one for any row returned. (0 where `resv_name_id is null`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some general tips to clean up your code, plus a solution:

As others have said, `NOT IN` clauses would be perfect here. Substitute them for those huge blocks of `!=` comparisons. You also want your `COUNT` and `SUM` functions to be outside the `CASE` statements, as shown below.

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE WHEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" = 'GDS' 
              AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" NOT IN ('BKIT', 'EXPEDIA', ...)
              AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."MARKET_CODE" NOT IN ('GOVG', 'ENT', ...)
         THEN 'GDS'
         ELSE 'Other'
    END AS "BizUnit",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" = 'GDS' 
              AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" NOT IN ('BKIT', 'EXPEDIA', ...)
              AND "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."MARKET_CODE" NOT IN ('GOVG', 'ENT', ...)
         THEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID"
         ELSE NULL
    END) AS "COST",
    ...
FROM
    "OPERA"."RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY" "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY
    ...
```

Your code was over 570 lines long. Some people consider 1/10 of that to be too much code. Notice how I snipped out the parts that aren't directly applicable to your issue? This is how you go about creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable working example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Excellent job cleaning up the query, and demonstrating the aggregation occurring outside the case statement. The only thing I would mention is that the `else 0` when getting the count output for `COST`, is that "0" will still be counted as a distinct value. The OP may need to clarify further.

Comment: Thank you, and good catch. OP, please don't take these critiques the wrong way. I understand we've all been new to this at one point in time. :)

Comment: @RobbieToyota As far as I know, there's no real way to get around that. If you simply ignore the `else` part, or put an explicit `else NULL` both would count as a distinct value, correct? Shy of pre-cleaning the data using a derived table or ETL process, I'm not sure what else one would do there.

Comment: I should note that you *could* change the `COUNT` to a `SUM` then your `CASE` would be `THEN 1 ELSE 0` which means it only counts a value if the condition is true. Also remove the `DISTINCT`, since you can't use `SUM` and `DISTINCT` together like that.

Comment: @McGlothlin. Definitely not taking this the wrong way. :) This code was wrote by someone else and needs lots and lots of clean up. When I run this code I get "missing right parenthesis"  within this line however : COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."SOURCE_CODE" = 'GDS'

Comment: That is because I missed a right parenthesis. :) updated the answer.

Comment: @Jacobm001, Only non-null values are included in count, so `else null` would drop the row from the count. Example `select count(distinct x) from (select null x from dual)` returns 0.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Oh, right hence the difference `count()` styles. Good call.

Comment: @McGlothlin - thank you so much for being so helpful! I've got over 100 pages of code to update here haha! The whole thing needs to be revamped!  The answer you provided was spot on! :)

Comment: @BuffaloBill You're quite welcome! Please don't forget to accept the answer since it worked for you.

Comment: @BuffaloBill I don't envy you for having that task in front of you! @McGlothlin: I should have clarified using `null` instead of `0`. Sorry for pointing out a problem without helping with a solution. :)

Comment: @RobbieToyota it's OK I knew what you meant.

Comment: @McGlothlin, where do I accept the answer on here haha? Also, yup I agree that null should be used.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's the checkmark by the answer. But now that there is another answer, you should accept the one that is most helpful to you. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and also here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @McGlothlin, actually now that I've looked at this a little further in Tableau it is still not counting distinct "RESV_NAME_ID" ?  Really strange stuff here.  It simply counts them all up.  Returns a count of 60k when it should be 17k, same as before.  Thanks again!

Comment: Check your `GROUP BY`, make sure you're grouping by the proper columns. Since you're using Oracle you could also use a windowing clause instead, if you want to group by different columns than you are selecting. This replaces a `GROUP BY` with an `OVER()`. See here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html

Comment: @McGlothlin - hey thanks again.  Hmmm, I don't see an issue with the GROUP BY clause here.  I have updated my existing code, as shown above.  See any issues there? I'm not sure why when I paste the code it looks fine, but then gets all jumbled up.  Sorry about that!

Comment: You have to indent 4 spaces to use code formatting. The best way is to go to your text editor and tab in once (assuming your tabs are four spaces), then paste it in.

Comment: @McGlothlin. Thank you! Looks much better.  Hopefully it is easier to look at now.  Been trying a bunch of different things and it still returns a total count and not a distinct.

Comment: Look at Thorsten Kettner's answer, point #3. You are still grouping by `RESV_NAME_ID`.

Comment: @McGlothlin - I tried removing the RESV_NAME_ID from the grouping, but I receive an error stating that it needs to be in the GROUP BY expression.

Comment: That's because you're still selecting that column. If you select it, it *must* be in the `GROUP BY`, but this is not required in a windowing clause (i.e. `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`). At this point I suggest you go read the Oracle documentation. I believe I've answered your original question (and you even accepted it at one point...). The comment thread is not intended for extended discussion, which is what this has turned into.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few remarks (too long for a comment):

1. `AND ("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" != 'BKIT' OR "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RATE_CODE" != 'EXPEDIA' )`? Think about that for a moment. When is that condition not met? The rate code will always be different from either one value or the other (usually both), except for NULL, where the result is "unknown".
2. `THEN COUNT(DISTINCT "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID") ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID") END) AS "COST"`. So in any case you count distinct `RESV_NAME_ID`. Why the `CASE` then?
3. As you group by `RESV_NAME_ID`, `COUNT(DISTINCT "RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."RESV_NAME_ID")` can always only be 1 in a group.
4. `sum(NVL("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."NIGHTS",0))` and `sum(NVL("RESERVATION_STAT_DAILY"."ROOM_REVENUE",0))`: `SUM` ignores nulls, so you don't have to make these zeros before adding them up. A sum, hoever, can be null, so you may want `NVL(SUM(NIGHTS), 0)` instead.
5. As to readablity: queries in all upper caps are hard to read. Either use lower case or mix the two (e.g. upper case for SQL keywords). As no column contains blanks or the like, you don't need quotes. As only one table is involved, you don't need a table qualifier. And if you did, you should have a short alias name for the table and use this instead of the whole name. And you should format the query with indentation, so we see the clauses (`FROM`, `GROUP BY` etc.) on first glance.